Angular template with component properties
I am trying to add a component property as a template variable to a template string. Something like this:
template: `
    <div fxFlexFill>
        <div
            class="wrapper"
            {{ templateVariable }}
            (dblclick)="reset()"></div>
    </div>
`

and templateVariable is:
templateVariable: string = '#abc'

I am getting a runtime error:
Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{' is not a valid attribute name.

Is it even possible what I am trying to do?
Thanks

No its not, what are you actually trying to solve, could you explain that, maybe there is a better way to solve your original problem!

It's hard for me to understand why you are even trying this.

I would like to control the names of the templates reference variables. So, the same component can run multiple times with different template reference variables.

But why do you want to have "different" names? What is the ultimate goal of this?

Fair question. I am going through some troubleshooting of a large application. The component has charts inside and these charts are not getting properly refreshed in certain situations. Controlling template variables is just a try to see where the problem is.

For debugging purposes, I think you can use a custom attribute/class etc. Or even better, you can use the debugger to see the context better.

@Mark try using angular devtools

That is not what I am asking.
